# Relationship between intersections

Tags: set-theory

Given $N$ sets $X_1, \dots, X_N$ and two definitions of intersection $\cap'$ and $\cap''$, is it possible to show that
$$
\vert X_i \cap' X_j \vert \le \vert X_i \cap'' X_j \vert,
\quad
\forall i,j \in \{ 1, \dots, N \}
$$
implies
$$
\vert X_{i_1} \cap' \dots \cap' X_{i_K} \vert
\le
\vert X_{i_1} \cap'' \dots \cap'' X_{i_K} \vert,
\quad
\forall X_{i_1} \dots X_{i_K} \in \mathcal{P}(\{ X_1, \dots, X_N \})?
$$

Comment: What is a definition of intersection?

Comment: There's only one "definition of intersection" I know about - what *exactly* do you mean, here?

Comment: Intersection is essentially related to a definition of identity: which elements of $X_i$ are identical to the elements of $X_j$. Consider two different definitions of identity, and you will correspondingly get two different definition of intersection for the same sets.

Comment: What is a definition of identity?

Comment: An equivalence relation

Comment: Suppose that the elements of the sets are objects. The first equivalence is "same color", the second is "same shape". If you look at the intersections based on these equivalence you will obtain different subsets.

Comment: You need to actually say that in the question - the language "two definitions of intersection" is totally unclear. Regardless, this seems more appropriate for MSE than MO.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, we have two equivalence relations on a set $X$ and subsets $X_1, \ldots, X_N \subseteq X$, and $|X_i \cap' X_j|$ and $| X_i \cap'' X_j|$ mean the number of equivalence classes which meet both $X_i$ and $X_j$, relative to the two equivalence relations, etc.

The answer is no. Let $X_1 = \{a,b,c\}$, $X_2 = \{a,b,d\}$, $X_3 = \{a,c,d\}$. Let the blocks of the first relation be $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c,d\}$ and let the second relation be the identity relation. Then for any $i \neq j$ exactly two blocks meet both $X_i$ and $X_j$, for either relation. But two blocks of the first relation meet all three sets, while only one block of the second does.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the example. Could you make the intersections/equivalences explicit?

Comment: $X_i\cap'X_j=X_i\cap'X_j\cap'X_k=\{\{a\},\{b,c,d\}\}$ if I understand correctly. Or, $b,c,d$ have the same color, but no two have the same shape.

Comment: What Gerry said. Four objects, all different shapes, but the last three have the same color. Every set contains both colors, but only the first shape belongs to all three sets.

Comment: Actually, my example is unnecessarily complicated. Take three objects, all the same color, all different shapes, and consider the sets $\{a,b\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{b,c\}$. Any two of these sets have one color and one shape in common, but all three have one color and no shapes in common.